# C# / Sockets: Receiving data and constructing a message from it

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to implement a system that can send and receive "Nessages" (a custom type) using **async Sockets.** Each Message consists of three elements:

First I send the Message-ID (4 bytes), next is the length of the data (4 bytes) and then the actual data.

The way TCP/IP works, I can not know if the full Message is in the buffer of data that I just received. I need to look for the InfoHeader (ID and length) first and use the remaining data to fill the Message's DataBuffer.

```
public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // How many bytes were received? They are now stored in the PacketBuffer
            int bytesReceived = Socket.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesReceived != 0)
            {
                // We did receive some data
                if (MessageInfoHeader.Length < NetProtocol.NetInfoHeaderSize)
                {
                    // The InfoHeader we have is not complete yet. How many bytes are missing from it?
                    int infoHeaderDataInCurrentBuffer = NetProtocol.NetInfoHeaderSize - (int) MessageInfoHeader.Length;

                    // Check if we have read enough data to fill the entire missing InfoHeader
                    if (infoHeaderDataInCurrentBuffer > bytesReceived)
                    {
                        // Nope, we dont. Fill as much as we can
                        infoHeaderDataInCurrentBuffer = bytesReceived;

                        Log.Info("We do not have enough data to complete the InfoHeader yet. Fill as much as we can");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.Info("We do have enough data to complete the InfoHeader");
                    }

                    // Now fill it from the chunk of data we just received
                    MessageInfoHeader.Write(ReceivedData, 0, infoHeaderDataInCurrentBuffer);

                    // See if there is any data remaining in the buffer that we can store in the MessageDataBuffer
                    int dataRemainingInPacket = bytesReceived - infoHeaderDataInCurrentBuffer;
                    Log.Info("DataRemainingInPacket: " + dataRemainingInPacket);

                    // Check again if we have the full header
                    if (MessageInfoHeader.Length == NetProtocol.NetInfoHeaderSize)
                    {
                        Log.Info("We now have assembled the full InfoHeader");

                        // We do have the full InfoHeader. Use the rest of the data to fill the DataBuffer
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            byte[] b = MessageInfoHeader.GetBuffer();
                            ms.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                            try
                            {
                                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms))
                                {
                                    CurrentMessageID = br.ReadInt32();
                                    CurrentMessageDataLength = br.ReadInt32();

                                    Log.Info("InfoHeader: MessageID=" + CurrentMessageID + " / DataLength=" + CurrentMessageDataLength);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }
                        }

                        if (dataRemainingInPacket > 0)
                        {
                            Log.Info("There are " + dataRemainingInPacket + " bytes remaining in the packet. Writing them to the PacketDataBuffer");

                            MessageDataBuffer.Write(ReceivedData, CurrentPacketBytesRead, ReceivedData.Length - CurrentPacketBytesRead);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageDataBuffer.Write(ReceivedData, 0, ReceivedData.Length);

                    if(ReceivedData.Length <= NetDataBufferSize)
                    {
                        Log.Info("WE HAVE RECEIVED THE ENTIRE MESSAGE");
                    }
                }

                // Start receiving the new TCP-Packet
                Socket.BeginReceive(ReceivedData, 0, ReceivedData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), null);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Info("No data has been received");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Retrieve the listening Socket
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        // Retrieve the Socket that is actually connected to the client
        Socket csocket = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        Log.Info("Accepted connection from: " + csocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Create a new client with the CSocket and add it to the list
        ClientConnection client = ClientManager.AddClient(csocket);

        // Start reading data from the Client's Socket and then enter the "read-loop" inside the client
        client.Socket.BeginReceive(client.ReceivedData, 0, (int) client.ReceivedData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(client.ReadCallback), null);

        // Turn the listener back into listening mode
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);
    }

    public const int NetInfoHeaderSize = 8; // 2x int

    public static byte[] FrameMessage(NetMessage message)
    {
        byte[] result;

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ms))
            {
                bw.Write(message.ID);
                bw.Write(message.Data.Length);
                bw.Write(message.Data);
            }

            result = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

This piece of code obviously does not work correctly. I get the "RECEIVED ENTIRE MESSAGE" line multiple times.

Question: What exactly am I doing wrong? I'm failing to wrap my head around what is the best way to handle something like this? Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Working Asunc Socket with string example: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/9638/asynchronous-socket#t=201704140557061436398 give it a look maybe there are some answers. And could you show the method who is firing the ReadCallback method?

Comment: @TimonPost I have added some more info. Scroll down in the code section!

Comment: `(ReceivedData.Length <= NetDataBufferSize`  looks like you're always showing this, when the data is read in multiple reads.

Comment: A while ago I wrote a method on receiving data from a socket async. It's easy to use and will handle multiple reads. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647492/read-asynchronously-data-from-networkstream-with-huge-amount-of-packets/42648492#42648492

Answer (score 0):

There could be quite a few problems. But the first one I can see for the loop on "RECEIVED ENTIRE MESSAGE" is that you are assuming the `ReceivedData` buffer has been filled entirely by `Socket.EndReceive(ar);` - which isn't the case, so a first troubleshooting start could be to rewrite this:

```
MessageDataBuffer.Write(ReceivedData, 0, ReceivedData.Length);
if (ReceivedData.Length <= NetDataBufferSize)
{
    Log.Info("WE HAVE RECEIVED THE ENTIRE MESSAGE");
}
```

to:

```
MessageDataBuffer.Write(ReceivedData, 0, bytesReceived);
if (MessageDataBuffer.Length <= NetDataBufferSize)
{
    Log.Info("WE HAVE RECEIVED THE ENTIRE MESSAGE");
}
```

Assuming that MessageDataBuffer is intended to contain the entire message